# Using numpy select to conditionally split a string in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm trying to use numpy.select to replace certain values with another values a pandas DataFrame column.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':['a','b','c', np.nan, 'a or b', 'bad or good', 'a;b']})
```

My desired output:

```
array(['x', 'b', 'c', np.nan, 'a', 'bad', 'x'])
```

I'm using the following code to do it:

```
np.select(condlist = [df['col']=='a', 
                      df['col'].str.contains(';', na=False), 
                      df['col'].str.contains('or', na=False)
                     ],
          choicelist = ['x', 
                        'x', 
                        df['col'].str.split(' or')[0]
                       ],
          default = df['col']
         )
```

but it throws up a ValueError:

`ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape`

I think the problem is with `df['col'].str.split(' or')[0]` because when I delete this option and the corresponding condition, the rest of the code works. How do I proceed from here?

Comment: What does `np.array(df['col'].str.split(' or')[0])` do?  `np.split` as a numpy function tries to turn all inputs into arrays.  Also does `traceback` tell you more about where the error occurs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us try

```
df['out'] = df.col.str.split('or|;').str[0].str.strip()
0      a
1      b
2      c
3    NaN
4      a
5    bad
6      a
Name: col, dtype: object
```

Comment: This is just one condition in numpy.select. Do I put this instead of `df['col'].str.split(' or')[0]` in choicelist?

Comment: @NewbieAF change to `df['col'].str.split(' or').str[0]`

Answer (score 0):

I would replace the `df['col'].str.split(' or')[0]`

with

```
temp = [s.split(' or')[0] for s in df['col'].values]
```

it is important that `None` or np.nan or whatever,is placed in the list if it does not contain ' or'. I'm not sure if the above list comprehension does that (you can check for yourself - and fix if it does not).

```
choicelist = ['x', 
              'x', 
              temp]
```

not sure if that will work but you could try it

Answer (score 0):

replace `df['col'].str.split(' or')[0]` with `df['col'].str.split(' or').str[0]`:

```py
np.select(condlist = [df['col']=='a', 
                      df['col'].str.contains(';', na=False), 
                      df['col'].str.contains('or', na=False)
                     ],
          choicelist = ['x', 
                        'x', 
                        df['col'].str.split(' or').str[0]
                       ],
          default = df['col']
         )``
```

---

```
df['col'].str.split(' or')

0             [a]
1             [b]
2             [c]
3             NaN
4         [a,  b]
5    [bad,  good]
6           [a;b]
Name: col, dtype: object


df['col'].str.split(' or')[0] always -> ['a']


df['col'].str.split(' or').str[0]

0      a
1      b
2      c
3    NaN
4      a
5    bad
6    a;b
Name: col, dtype: object
```

Comment: This is just one condition in numpy.select. Do I put this instead of `df['col'].str.split(' or')[0]` in choicelist?